# Java 1.6: Pass generic interface to generic class

Tags: java, generics

I've the following interface:

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    boolean valid(T object);
}
```

Now I want to write a class

```
class MyClass<S extends MyInterface<T>>) {
    public S doSomething(T object) {
        ...
    }  
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

When I implement it like above I get the message "Cannot resolve symbol T".

EDIT: Why I'm asking?

When I've an implementation of the interface

```
class MyInterfaceImpl<Double> {
    boolean valid(Double object)
}
```

And a class like this

```
class SomeClass() {
    private MyClass<Double, MyInterfaceImpl> myClass;
}
```

then "Double" is duplicate in some way, so I hoped that there is any way to get rid of the Double, so that it looks like

```
class SomeClass() {
    private MyClass<MyInterfaceImpl> myClass;
}
```

Thank you
Torben

Comment: did you try: `class MyClass<T, S extends MyInterface<T>> {`?

Comment: What Marco said; also you've got a (I assume) typo after MyInterface<T> your ')' should be another '>'

Comment: Ok, this works. But then I've to write `MyClass<ClassA, ClassB> myClass = new MyClass()` when `ClassB` implements `MyInterface<ClassA>`. But I want to get rid of the duplicate ClassA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this : (as Marco Forberg also suggested)

```
class MyClass<T, S extends MyInterface<T>> {

    public S doSomething(T object) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to get rid of this "duplicate" T?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
boolean valid(T object);
}

class MyClass<T, S extends MyInterface<T>> {
public S doSomething(T object) {
 ...
}
```

works fine...